# Google cloud functions cannot deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am following the tutorial for google cloud functions. 
Trying to deploy the hello world from command line returns

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) value for field [locationsId] for in collection [cloudfunctions.projects.locations] is required but was not provided

deploy command is

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --stage-bucket shopping-functions --trigger-topic hello_world
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@jdabello said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981207/2267825), I attached `--region` option to my command and it solves the problem as follows:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --stage-bucket your-bucket --trigger-topic hello_world --region=us-central1
```

Or you can set your default functions/region using `gcloud config set` and you can skip specifying function's region each time.

```
gcloud config set functions/region us-central1
```

Comment: Was about to say this - this is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you don't have a project set up properly?

Have you set up a project from which you want to use your cloud function? You can look it up by calling `gcloud info`. You can also try reinitializing your environment with `gcloud init`.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed any functions using the "firebase deploy" command? I was having the same problem until I switched all of my functions to either gcloud or firebase. It seems they don't play well together yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set a region for your function. You can add the --region flag to override the default functions/region property value for this command invocation.